# How to update gridview when selectedvalue of combobox is changed WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, combobox

Well what I'm trying to do is I have a table which has information about all the patient.
I have retrieved names of all the patient in **combobox**.
Now what I have to do is when a user selects particular name from combobox then the **gridview** should get updated with the details of selected patient..

I have searched a lot on this but was unable to find the exact help.
I'm new to WPF technology so any help would do.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hi so using a GridView is mostly used to set a specific layout not to display data. What you want to do is use a DataGrid and than set the ItemsSource to it.

In the case that you want to display only a single "row" of information than you should probably use a Label and set it's Content.

Hope this helps